# Do not Redraw command line buffer in Vim after :ls

Tags: vim, neovim

One of NeoVim build in feature is: when you type `:ls` it shows the **Buffer list** with open files in it, and then when you enter another command to switch to specific buffer like `:b<number>` that command line buffer do not redraw and [you could see all opened buffers:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m07Su.jpg)

So the question is it possible to activate such a function in Vim, and if so, how?

Comment: That *is* the default behavior in Vim. After `:ls` you get the "Press ENTER ..." prompt and if you type `:` to start another command, the previous output isn't cleared... If you're seeing otherwise, could it be something from your vimrc? Try `vim --clean` or `vim -u NONE` and see if you still get that same unexpected behavior...

Comment: FWIW, I’ve adapted my workflow slightly after reading https://vimways.org/2019/making-things-flow/

Comment: @filbranden - thanks for the idea you gave, it was my fault - I had to check this version first before ask that question here.

Comment: Totally ok! If you did find the problem, feel free to self-answer with what happened to cause the behavior you were seeing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this problem was custom status line plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `command Ls :ls<CR>:b<Space>`, and set a key mapping to `Ls`.

See [this article](https://vimways.org/2019/making-things-flow/) for more setups of the like.

Comment: `myls` is an invalid name for a user command (must be `Myls`, `Ls` or such).